# Elasticsearch: Filter (or Query) by Term Frequency

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I run an elasticsearch query that only returns results with the term X mentioned at least Y times in a document?

For example, suppose you had a footer in all of your indexed documents that say something like `copyright 2013`.  Suppose when the user runs a search for the term `copyright`, you want to be smart and only show those documents that say the word `copyright` twice (otherwise you'll return all documents). I know there are multiple ways of accomplishing this, but one way, would be to run a filter that returns only those documents that use the term copyright twice. Does such a filter exist?

I could envision something like this, but I don't see anything comparable in the docs:

```
"filter" : {
            "term" : { "user" : "copyright"},
            "frequency" : { "gt" : 1 }
        }
```

Considering that Elasticsearch stores term frequencies, I would expect that this would be possible to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [script filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html) in which you access the [term frequency](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html#_term_statistics_2) of `copyright` in field `user` using something like `_index['user']['copyright'].tf()`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "_index['name'][term_to_lookup].tf() > occurrences",
          "params": {
            "term_to_lookup": "copyright",
            "occurrences": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since ~Elasticsearch 5.5, term frequency is no longer available to scripts. You must now use a script engine.